# Do quaternions follow the rule for simplifying logarithms of products?

Tags: logarithms, quaternions

The logarithm of a quaternion $q$ that has a real part $a$ and imaginary parts $v$ is defined as

$$ \ln q = \ln a + \hat{v} \arccos \frac{a}{\left\lvert q \right\rvert} $$

The exponentional of a quaternion $q$ that has a real part $a$ and imaginary parts $v$ is defined as

$$ \exp q = e^a \left(\cos \left\lvert v\right\rvert+ \hat{v} \sin \left\lvert v \right\rvert\right) $$

Is it true that for all purely imaginary quaternions that:

$$ \ln (\exp u * \exp v) = u + v $$
$$ c u = \ln (\exp u)^c $$

I have a math program I wrote which seems to be inaccurate and want to know if the bug is in my program or in my idea of quarternions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true, and as usual the problem is lack of commutativity. The correct statement in general is surprisingly complicated and is given by the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula).

(You already have to be a bit careful with this rule for complex numbers, but for quaternions it just totally goes out the window.)